# Intercept Hotkey globally, but keep original behaviour

Tags: java, clipboard, hotkeys

I try to intercept to the `Copy&Paste` Hotkey using Java. 
For attaching Hotkeys globally, I used [JKeyMaster](https://github.com/tulskiy/jkeymaster), which worked fine for
attaching Hotkeys on different OS.

This time, though, I don't want to attach a new Hotkey onto the OS. I just want to execute code in between. So I want to add a Hotkey onto <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and when I press it, globally, I want it to execute my custom behaviour before or after (doesn't matter) the OS event was handled.

So for example, if I have the Text: `"Test Text"` in my Clipboard and I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, before the paste happens, I want to change the Clipboard Text to `"New Text"`.

Is there a library, I can use to not overwrite, but just intercept a global Hotkey?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html

Comment: I know how to access the Clipboard. The problem is I need to know when. Exactly when CTRL+V is pressed, or after. So I need to hook up this key Event globally. But all Libraries I found only overwrite the standard behaviour. And that's not what I want to do.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook). From the [keyboard listener example](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Usage#global-keyboard-listener) (slightly altered):

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {

    boolean isCtrlDown = false;

    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_CONTROL_L || e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_CONTROL_R) {
            System.out.println("Ctrl pressed");
            isCtrlDown = true;
        }

        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_V && isCtrlDown) {
            System.out.println("User hit Ctrl+V");
        }
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_CONTROL_L || e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_CONTROL_R) {
            System.out.println("Ctrl released");
            isCtrlDown = false;
        }
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        }
        catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }

        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
    }
}
```

This would be a bit buggy because if one hit the left and the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keys and then released one of them but not the other, `isCtrlDown` would be `false`. I don't know if this would work on macs as I don't know the key combo to paste on them.

Comment: I can't get the `.jar` file built with ant. Even though I used the wiki as a manual. I'm probably missing some tool. This is a huge overhead of doing stuff, why not simply providing the `.jar` file within github? Can't test your code that way, sorry.

Comment: There are releases... Alright. Tested this and it looks quite good. I wasn't able to implement the code to my actual problem, but I was able to get the code executed (`System.out`) after the paste event actually finished. So this is exactly what I wanted. Thank you